# Error installing APK on Android (App has not been installed)

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, installation, apk

I have created an app with Android Studio - here I have installed API levels 19  (Android 4.4 Kitkat) as well as 25 (Android 7.1.1 Nougat).

My phone for testing is 7.1.1

The settings of the app are:
Compile SDK Version 7.1.1
Build tools 25.0.2

Min SDK: 19
Target SDK: 25

On my phone (7.1.1) it is running wel but when I sign the APK, and try to install it on Android 6.0.1, it tries to install and then brings the error:

App has not been installed.

What do I do wrong here?

This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
package="it.wieland.newsclub"
platformBuildVersionCode="25"
platformBuildVersionName="7.1.1">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.VERSION"
    android:value="25.3.1" />
.....
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running your app on android 6.0.1 via avd, try setting the target sdk version to the required android 6.0.1 api level and not 25 which corresponds to android 7.1 Also set multidexenabled =true in your app level build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I left everything as it was.
Only when signing the APK I choose not only V2 (Full APK Signature) but also V1 (JAR Signature).

Now I can install it also on 6.0.1.